# Android elevation of View in CardView is not shown

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-cardview, android-elevation

I have a RelativeLayout inside a CardView that i want to elevate in Android Lollipop but the elevation is not shown (the shadow is not shown):

[image]

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android.support.v7.cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/CardViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation="5dp">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/article_thumb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/article_thumb"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/article_title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/article_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/article_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
        android:textColor="@color/gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/article_title"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/article_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/article_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        android:translationZ="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/redbubble"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/redbubble" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_comment_bubble"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So inside this layout I added this two lines to the RelativeLayout to make the elevation:

```
android:elevation="30dp"
android:translationZ="30dp"
```

Anyone an idea why it is not shown? At the moment I test it with a Emulator using Android API 21 (Lollipop).

Comment: Are you trying to cast a shadow from that dialog bubble shape? If so, it won't work because shadows are only supported for convex shapes. You could try setting an outline provider for a rounded-rect shape, though.

Comment: Yes I want to have a shadow for this bubble shape.

Comment: Try the solution on this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/27900541/1972566

Comment: in my case it was a transparent background of view with elevation

Answer (score 10):

In the root layout in the xml you need

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

below is the code for a cardview

```
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
```

Answer (score 5):

The shadow is not shown because they are drawn outside of the bounds of he RelativeLayout and the view is cliped to its bound.

Add `android:clipChildren="false"` to the parent of your RelativeLayout or add a small amount of padding to your View and set `android:clipToPadding="false"`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. If I use `android:clipChildren="false"` then my whole layout is out of bounds so I tried the second approach and added `android:padding="5dp"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"` to my RelativeLayout. But the shadow is still not shown. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should add **android:elevation** property to the redbubble imageview.
To view Shadow of an element you have to add  **android:elevation** to that view.

I would suggest you to change your redbubble imageview to the following :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/redbubble"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/redbubble" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I thinks the answer from alanv in the main post describes the problem

Comment: You can add your custom shadow for the redbubble and set it as background.
android:background="@drawable/myCustomShadowShape" />

Answer (score 1):

I noticed same problem and elevation is not shown because line:

> android:layout_below="@+id/...."

Generally, it is because shadow is drawn outside of visible bounds.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false" from manifest
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44173464/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.