# CardView shadow not appearing in Lollipop after obfuscate with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-cardview

My CardView's shadows have disappeared on Lollipop devices after applying Proguard. I haven't defined any rule to protect this library, because I haven't read it was necessary at all.

I attach you a couple of screenshots, first without running proguard, and secon after running it.

[Screenshot without proguard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BszL.png)

[Screenshot with proguard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PSSp.png)

And this is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:contentPadding="10dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 1"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:contentPadding="10dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 2"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity only sets the xml as content and does nothing more.
As you can see, I'm using the two possibilities of `cardUseCompatPadding`, but it doesn't solve the issue as it's defined in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653781/cardview-shadow-not-appearing-in-lollipop-devices/27658827).

Does anybody know why proguard is breaking my shadows?

Comment: If you found your own solution, you can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna copy it down here

Answer (score 9):

After some diving in the library packages, I wrote a rule that protected everything at android.support.** and now I'm finally protecting just android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawable.

So if you are having troubles with this, just add the next rule at your proguard config:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawable { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there are some good online collections of the Proguard rules required for each library, e.g. https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/

It looks like your Proguard rule has already been absorbed into that project, and it links back to this Stackoverflow question. :-)
https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-support-v7-cardview.pro

Comment: Yes, I added there via [this PR](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/pull/33) :)