# Card view shadow is not showing

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardview

This is my **card_view**. I have mentioned  `card_view:cardElevation`.
But **still shadow is not showing**.
    I have searched many links. Everywhere they have mentioned to use `card_view:cardElevation`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Can you tell what I am missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cardview shadow not appearing in lollipop devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653781/cardview-shadow-not-appearing-in-lollipop-devices)

Comment: Try `app:cardElevation="5dp"` this might work

Answer (score 4):

Read https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

> To create a card with a shadow, use the card_view:cardElevation
>   attribute. CardView uses real elevation and dynamic shadows on Android
>   5.0 (API level 21) and above and falls back to a programmatic shadow implementation on earlier versions. For more information, see
>   [Maintaining
>   Compatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html).

UPDATE

**try adding margin to card if you want to see shadow**

check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html

Comment: I am using card_view:cardElevation. still shadow is not comming. and i am testing it on Lollipop Device also

Comment: Isnt this helpful?@ananya

Comment: No @Amit.
I got the solution.
Actually in my manifest file this one was false( android:hardwareAccelerated="false")
I make it as ture and then it worked

Comment: What is solution than @ananya

Comment: check that comment @Amit. I edited the solution there

Comment: Actually in my manifest file this one was false( android:hardwareAccelerated="false") .
I make it as ture and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following attribute in your `cardview`

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding = "true"
card_view:cardElevation = "5dp"
```